# WKB application on symmetric potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical, instantons

I am a little confused how one can find a wave function by using WKB approximation? I do know the oscillation frequency $$\Omega ~=~ {2E\over h}{\rm Re} \langle L|R \rangle~=~ {E\over \pi\hbar}{\rm Re} \langle L|R \rangle, $$

where $L$, $R$ are the eigenstate of the left and right well.

However, the key of finding this inner product is a pain to me, can someone teach me through it?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is just a practice from our instructor (He made it up), the formula above is on his lecture slides (at least I don't see it on the Griffith)....But the concern I have is how can one find a wavefunction on both left and right well?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please avoid pasting text, include only relevant images/plots and input the relevant information in text form, to allow questions to be searched.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. In Ref. 1 it is claimed that
   $$ \frac{2\pi}{\tau}~=~\Omega~=~\frac{E_n^--E_n^+}{\hbar}~=~\frac{\omega}{\pi}e^{-\phi},\tag{8.63/8.64}$$
   where
   $$ \phi~\equiv~ \int_{-x_1}^{x_1} \!dx |k(x)|, \tag{8.60}$$
   so that
   $$ \phi \sim~ \alpha a^2 \quad \text{for} \quad V(0)\gg E   \quad \text{where} \quad \alpha~\equiv~ \frac{m\omega}{\hbar}.$$
2. Now let's for simplicity assume $n=0$. If we define $$\begin{align}\psi_{R/L}(x)~=~&A\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}(x\mp a)^2\right)~=~\psi_{L/R}(-x), \cr A~\equiv~& \left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right)^{1/4},\end{align}$$
   to be the $E_0=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$ ground state in the right/left well
   $$ V_{R/L}(x)~=~\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x\mp a)^2, $$
   then indeed
   $$\begin{align}\langle L | R\rangle~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx~\psi_L(x)\psi_R(x)\cr
   ~=~&\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dx~\exp\left(-\alpha(x^2+ a^2)\right)\cr
   ~=~&e^{-\alpha a^2}~\sim~e^{-\phi}. \end{align}$$

References:

1. D. Griffiths, *Intro to QM,* 1995; problem 8.15.
2. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *QM,* Vol. 3, 2nd & 3rd ed, 1981; $\S50$ problem 3.

Comment: Additional references: 3. Yoichi Kazama, [_Instantons in QM_](http://hep1.c.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Ekazama/QFT/instanton2.pdf).